# Get a Json array from a SignalR hub function as a string in javascript using signalR

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, signalr

I am trying to get a json array as a string via a function on the server using signalR but I keep getting an object instead of a string.
This is the code that writes the json array.

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
        int fields = reader.FieldCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < fields; i++)
        {
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(reader.GetName(i));
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(reader[i]);
        }

        jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();

    }
    jsonWriter.WriteEndArray();
}
reader.Close();
con.Close();

return sb.ToString();
```

This is the result i got from this function:

```
{[{"ResponseCode":"","NodeName":"Test"},  {"ResponseCode":"00","NodeName":"Test"}]}
```

And my javascript code is:

```
var standetails = hub.server.stanDetails($(this).textContent);
//var x = JSON.parse(standetails)
```

the type of standetails in the browser is `object` and does not contain the json array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler than you thought. SignalR is going to serialize the custom object sent as parameter from server to JS client.
Which means you can actually send a list of complex object and you are getting an array on the JS side.

A simple examlpe:

Let's say this is your complex class:

```cs
public class TestData {
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime p3 { get; set; }
}
```

Let's make simple method which creates a list of this and sends

```cs
public class TestHub : Hub {
    public void Send(string name, string message) {
        List<TestData> testList = new List<TestData>();

        testList.Add(new TestData { p1 = "AAA", p2 = "BBB", p3 = DateTime.Now });
        testList.Add(new TestData { p1 = "CCC", p2 = "DDD", p3 = DateTime.Now });

        Clients.All.sendMessage(testList);
    }
}
```

javascript receiving this event:

```
var hub = $.connection.testHub;

hub.client.sendMessage = function (param) {
    console.log(param);
}
```

test here is an array containing tow objects, see on the image.
I hope this helps.

[image: debug screenshot]

**EDIT**

If you want to change the default serializer behavior, you can go by [replacing the default JsonSerializer used](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility#user-content-replacing-the-ijsonserializer), or the simple way would be to wrap in custom object.

Extending example with container class:

```
public class Container {
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Sending as serialized string:

```
Clients.All.sendMessage(new Container { value = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(testList) });
```

Receiving same javascript code.
Console log capture:

[image: debug screenshot2]

Comment: Thanks I knew this, I just wanted to know why I was not getting the string or an object containing the string in `standetails`

Comment: Because of the default serializer's behavior. You can override it. Read here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Extensibility#user-content-replacing-the-ijsonserializer.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide more info

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I needed :)